# How to cross reference a section and item in a list in single document?

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I want to cross reference sections as well as some items in the list in my document.
for ex:
`\label` helps us to cross reference the sections. If we renew the command to provide the cross reference for any item in an item, then its not available for section reference. But how can we do both in a single document?

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference in using `\label`-`\ref` when it comes to sectioning commands or enumerated lists. Here is an example showing how to properly use it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{sec:label}
Here is some text.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item An item
  \item Another item \label{enum:label}
\end{enumerate}
Reference to section~\ref{sec:label} and item~\ref{enum:label}.
\end{document}​​​
```

For more advanced (even automated) enumerated list labelling/referencing, you can use the `label` and `ref` options to `enumerate` provided by the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).

Comment: how about custom lists like starlist(*) or bulletlist?

Comment: @volatNumbers: For "custom lists" you would need to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), since there may be many variables at play. Note that referencing requires a counter. If you have no counter, for the reference, you have to do something different.

Comment: @Werner: It would be possible to refer to the page where the label is placed, `p.~\pageref{customlist:label}` (with `\phantomsection` before the `\label{customlist:label}`, if hyperref is used) - depends on the wishes of the OP (you named it: MWE!).